# Good Font for Unicode Symbols

Tags: fonts, unicode

I'm looking for a good font for displaying Unicode, specifically I'm after a complete set of U2400-U2800. In Firefox I get most of it, but in my application I've tried Arial Unicode MS, Lucida Unicode MS, Calibri, Times New Roman, Courier New, Symbol, and Serif, most on recommendation from pages I found through Googling, some from Firefox defaults, but I'm consistently missing U2680-U26A0 and a couple other smaller blocks.

The reference charts at [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/) of course display the complete range, but they don't identify the fonts used (presumably to avoid the threat of piracy, though that seems quite self-defeating to me). Extraction of the fonts (to get names only) via fontforge or various web services fails as the fonts appear to be contained within encrypted sections which are unsupported (another anti-piracy measure...*sigh*).

So, if anyone could recommend a more complete Unicode font (free or reasonably priced is best), I'd be very much obliged.

Cheers,

Ehtyar.

Comment: I didn't post this question to StackOverflow as it seemed a little too general. Please let me know if I should do so regardless.

Comment: No, this seems like a good place for it. Interesting question, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Here that range is mostly filled by Deja Vu Sans, STIXGeneral, VL Gothic, UnDotum, and... "MiscFixed", whatever that is (in the OCR section). Only holes at U+244A, U+24EB through U+24FF, U+269D, U+26BA through U+26BC, U+26C0 through U+26C3, and U+27CA remain.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not as a common an issue as I expected. For anyone else interested in this question, I'm currently using [Code2000](http://www.code2000.net/code2000_page.htm) and [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) to make up the set.

Answer (score 1):

Try Everson Mono font, which has nearly as many non-CJK glyphs as Code2000, especially in the U2400 to U2800 range.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows 10, then **Segoe UI Emoji** has these characters, but it is a specifically dingbats font, so besides those it has Latin script only.

**Segoe UI Symbol** has even more other characters. 
Both are present by default.
If you are on older Windows then you could try copy those fonts.
.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Doulos SIL](http://www.sil.org/computing/catalog/show_software.asp?id=91) has good coverage of writing systems based on the latin and cyrillic alphabets. No real italics, though, which is a great drawback.