# Greek and unicode

Tags: unicode

I'm doing a small project on the greek letters and I noticed there a few unicode symbols that I can't view.

[Two webpages with letters I can't see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgPc5.jpg)

I should mention that in the Character Map tool of Windows, when *Arial Unicode MS* is selected as a font, I don't see these symbols.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I am running Windows 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good Font for Unicode Symbols](http://superuser.com/questions/154293/good-font-for-unicode-symbols)

Comment: You must install another font. You can find and test a font that contains Greek letters in [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts).